# Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() thread is alive althoughTimeout is 0L

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executors

I was using `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and I am a bit confused about how it works. Let's say I am not calling `shutdown()`. I looked at the available source code 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29
 and it says:

```
public static ExecutorService  newSingleThreadExecutor() {
  return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService(new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
     0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()));
}
```

So, my assumption is after a task is executed even if I do not call shutdown() the thread should be stopped and a new Thread should be created if I call a task again on the same executor. But when I ran a code it gave a different output. Can someone explain the behavior?
Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<String> f = es.submit(new MyService());
    System.out.println(f.get());
    System.out.println("Done executing 1st run");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    f = es.submit(new MyService());
    System.out.println(f.get());
    es.shutdown();
}


public class MyService implements Callable<String>{

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Old name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Mythread: " + Math.random());
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

}
```

Here's the output:

```
Old name: pool-1-thread-1
Mythread: 0.061937241356848194
Done executing 1st run
Old name: Mythread: 0.061937241356848194
Mythread: 0.49829755639701667
```

I thought the `Old name:` in the 4th line should be `pool-1-thread-1` as the existing thread has a timeout of 0L. So, a new thread should be created. **Instead it is using the previous thread**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the maximum and minimum number of threads to 1,so the timeout is ignored because there will never be any additional threads to timeout.

The output you give doesn't make sense as there is no thread name the second time.  Also if your thread stopped and a new one created, it would be called `pool-1-thread-2`

Comment: I didn't quite get you. The initial code is from Executors source code. So, if I write maximum and minimum number of threads to 1 then the timeout parameter does not matter? The second time the thread name is same as the one I set the first time, so that I know its using the old Thread

Comment: From the ThreadPoolExecutor API Docs: _If the pool currently has more than corePoolSize threads, **excess** threads will be terminated if they have been idle for more than the keepAliveTime (see getKeepAliveTime(TimeUnit))._ The timeout is for the excess threads, that are the ones which are created above the core threads. You defined the core pool size to 1, the maximum to 1, so there _never_ will be excess threads to be terminated.

Comment: @SubhomoySikdar So this is what I would expect to happen.  If there is no thread to timeout, the timeout doesn't apply.

Comment: Thank you  P.J.Meisch. The keepAliveTime applies to excess threads above core size. Anyway to figure out how long the core threads will stay alive if I do not call shutdown? Or I am thinking they would/should be alive indefinitely as that is the core size, so the pool would always maintain that number of threads.

Comment: Thank you Peter Lawrey and P.J.Meisch. I believe I understood why the thread was not terminated.

Comment: core threads stay alive until shutdown. That's on purpose, so they are always available without delay. It's important not to forget to shutdown your threadpools at the end of the program, otherwise the JVM will not terminate.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I need the ThreadFactory constructor version for that I guess. Never used that for that purpose, might come in handy, thanks for the hint.